# Is there a way to have my second action animation start at the last location of my first action animation?

Tags: animation, path, origin, actions

I have a scene with a character that will complete multiple action animations. The problem I keep running into is that when the character transitions from action 1(walk) to action 2(looking behind) the character slides backward to action 1's start origin. Is there a way for me to have action 2 start at the end of action 1's animation. I've tried moving the character while in object mode and recording in the timeline but it changes the origin location of action 1 animation. [image: As shown in the picture the origin of action 1 animation is making my action 2 animation slide backward to the action 1's start origin.]

Answer (score -1):

For anyone with a similar problem to mine, I found the best way to resolve this issue is by adding a path for my character to follow. Using the shortcut Shift A, and selecting the Path option under Curve. I completed these steps in Object mode. I suggest searching for videos on how to create a path for walk cycles if you need further help with that step, I found many great resources on youtube.